# Angularjs: How do you use ng-show?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to check if something exists and show a button based on that. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

My code looks like this:

```
$scope.isURL = function(url) {
    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        if (data === 302) {
            return true
        }
    });
};
```

my HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="foo in foos">
    <button ng-hide="isURL(foo.url)">visit site</button>
    <button ng-show="isURL(foo.url)">remove bookmark?</button>
</ul>
```

Error loop I'm getting:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you are setting up a binding on a function that is returning a new promise each time.

The [`$digest`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24digest) cycle is going to fire, and evaluate the result of your function and determine that the result has changed, making it dirty. This will trigger another `$digest` loop that will continue ad infinitum.

A better option would be to check each of the urls, and set a property on the `foo` objects if they are good.

```
app.controller('displayCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function(scope,$http){
  var foos = [
    {name: 'foo-1', url:'assets/foo.html'},
    {name: 'foo-2', url:'assets/bad.html'}
  ];

  angular.forEach(foos, function(foo){
    $http.get(foo.url).success(function (data) {
       if(data === 302){
         foo.isUrl = true;
       }
    });
  });

  scope.foos = foos;
}]);
```

Which you can then bind to in your markup like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="foo in foos">
  <button ng-hide="foo.isUrl">visit site</button>
  <button ng-show="foo.isUrl">remove bookmark?</button>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this instead:

```
$scope.urls = {};

$scope.isURL = function(url) {
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.urls[url])) {
        $scope.urls[url] = false;
        $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            if (data === 302) {
                $scope.urls[url] = true;
            }
            return data;
        });
    }
    return $scope.urls[url];
};
```

That will also prevent you from checking each URL more than once.  I am not sure why you are checking for `data === 302`, but I assume you know what you are doing there.  If you are trying to check the status code, that will not work, you would need to use this instead:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 302) {
        $scope.urls[url] = true;
    }
    return response;
});
```

**Edit**

Documentation on how to use `ngShow` (and other directives) can be found on the AngularJS [web site](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow).  The if the expression evaluated in the `ngShow` directives is truthy the element will be shown.  In your code sample, `$scope.isURL(...)` does not return a value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I'm still getting the error loop in my console & the site becomes non-responsive. I don't want to actually show the url, just show a certain button depending on the response

Comment: The issue is that the function itself is returning a promise, not a scalar. As of Angular 1.2 promises are no longer unwrapped automatically by the framework when bound in the UI.